# No me imprime resultados

Tags: c, imprimir, inicializacion

Hola cómo andan estoy tratando de hacer una tarea consiste en imprimir al jugador que más goles hizo y al que menos hizo. Quiero imprimir en vez del número del dorso que  el nombre. Probé con char pero no logro que imprima correctamente.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int NombreJugador, JugadorconMasGoles, JugadorconMenosGoles, c = 1;
    int Numero;
    int Goles, MasGoles, MenosGoles;
    char j;

    do {
        MenosGoles = 0;
        printf("\n Ingrese el numero del dorso del jugador: ");
        scanf(" %i", &Numero);
        printf("\n Ingrese Cantidad de Goles: ");
        scanf(" %i", &Goles);

        if (MenosGoles <= Goles) {

            JugadorconMenosGoles = Numero;
            MenosGoles = Goles;
        }
        if (MasGoles < MenosGoles) {
            JugadorconMasGoles = Numero;
            MasGoles = Goles;

            printf("%i", JugadorconMasGoles);
        }

        printf("\n %c Desea agregar otro jugador (y/n)?: ", 168);
        scanf(" %c", &j);
    } while (j != 'n');

    printf("######RESULTADO DE LA COMPETENCIA###### :\n");
    printf("El Jugador Ganador: %i\n", JugadorconMasGoles);
    printf("Cantidad De Goles: %i\n", MasGoles);
    printf("El Jugador Perdedor: %i\n", JugadorconMenosGoles);
    printf("Cantidad De Goles: %i\n", MenosGoles);

    getch(); /* Pausa */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tenga en cuenta que `conio.h` es un archivo de cabecera en C utilizado con los antiguos compiladores de MS-DOS para crear interfaces de usuario de texto. Los compiladores que se dirigen a otros sistemas operativos, como Windows de 32 bits y OS/2 basados en Linux, proporcionan una funcionalidad equivalente a través de otros archivos de encabezado y bibliotecas. `#include <curses.h>` le dará prácticamente toda la funcionalidad proporcionada por `conio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Falta inicializar algunas de las variables que usas. Y el chequeo de maximo y minimo no es correcto.

Para la inicialización puedes usar los maximo y minimo del tipo de dato(y no cambiar su valor a no ser que se cumpla el chequeo -> quitar la línea MenosGoles = 0;). Están incluidos en climits.

```
#include <climits>
int Goles, MasGoles=INT_MIN, MenosGoles=INT_MAX;
```

Para comprobar máximo y mínimo hay que modificar las condiciones de los if:

```
if (MenosGoles >= Goles) {
...
}
if (MasGoles <= Goles) {
...
}
```

También habría que inicializar JugadorconMasGoles y JugadorconMenosGoles a valores conocidos y tener en cuenta que en la primera inserción se van a cumplir ambas condiciones